# Java Play! 2 - password constraints

Tags: java, constraints, playframework-2.0

I can't find an @Equal constraint in Play! 2.

I looked through the API
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/index.html

I want to have a SignupForm that checks if the passwords are equal. I don't believe that I have to write my own constraint for such a common problem.

Something like:

```
...
@Min(6)
public String password;
@Equal(password)
public String confirmPassword;
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't any `@Equal` contraint in other Java framework neither in the JSR 303.

To check for password, it's not difficult: in your form object, just write a `public String validate()` method:

```
public class SignupForm {

    @Min(6)
    public String password;

    @Min(6)
    public String confirmPassword;

    public String validate() {
        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            return "Password mismatch";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Take a look at the [zentask sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/), in this [class](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java#L14).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this question from google.  This is what I did

```
    @MinLength(6)
    public String password;

    @MinLength(6)
    public String confirmPassword;

    public List<ValidationError> validate(){
        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        if(!this.password.equals(this.confirmPassword)){
            errors.add(new ValidationError("password", "Passwords must match."));
        }
        return errors.isEmpty() ? null : errors;
    }
```

You have to use `@MinLength(6)` instead of `@Min(6)`, I think that's because password is a string.  Returning a List of validation errors will show up as an error in your form if someone doesn't enter a matching password.  Otherwise, they won't see what is wrong.

I found useful information here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms

Answer (score 0):

The below code returns global error.

```
public String validate() {
   if(!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
      return "Password mismatch";
   }
    return null;
}
```

But the snippet below more specifically returns error specific to confirmPassword field.

```
public List<ValidationError> validate(){
   List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
   if(!this.password.equals(this.confirmPassword)){
       errors.add(new ValidationError("confirmPassword", "Password should be same."));
    }
    return errors.isEmpty() ? null : errors;
}
```

[Here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms) is the official documentation that describes more on this.